# SQL VALUES and MAX across tables

Tags: sql, db2

I'm having an issue with a DB2 database query.
We have three tables, each with their own "last update timestamp" (LST_UPDT_TS).
We need to order the table by the this timestamp, using the most recent one found in any of the three tables.
As near as I can tell, the recommended method is to build a miniature internal table using "VALUES" and select the latest one, treating it as the timestamp for the amalgamated record.

```
SELECT
    a.CUST_ID as CUSTOMER_ID,
    (
        SELECT MAX(LST_UPDT_TS)
        FROM ( VALUES(
            (a.LST_UPDT_TS),
            (b.LST_UPDT_TS),
            (c.LST_UPDT_TS)
        ) as VALUE(LST_UPDT_TS)
            )
    ) as LST_UPDT_TS
FROM TableA as a
JOIN TableB as b ON b.CUST_ID = a.CUST_ID
JOIN TableC as c ON c.CUST_ID = a.CUST_ID
```

From what I can tell from the other solutions I've found here on StackOverflow, this is the proper format for using the SELECT and VALUES commands but instead of getting a single greatest value, I get...

> SQL0104N Unexpected token token "(" was found following "(". Expected tokens may include: ".  JOIN INNER LEFT RIGHT FULL CROSS".  SQLSTATE=42601 (#-104)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just to use `MAX (a.LST_UPDT_TS, b.LST_UPDT_TS, c.LST_UPDT_TS)` instead of this subselect?

Comment: Mark - To be blunt, I'm not all that good with SQL in spite of having to use it quite a bit.  I'm concerned because I did leave off that all of the tables are fairly large and I do need to do the results in batches of 1000 for sending to a remote requesting program.  Would this solution work when I'm having to do a "and (the combined max ts) > "(last ts of the previous batch) order by (combined ts) ASC fetch first 1000 rows only"?

Comment: Yes, it will work. This is an ordinal scalar function, which call may be used in whatever expressions and clauses including those you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,MAX(LST_UPDT_TS)LST_UPDT_TS 
from(
SELECT a.CUST_ID as CUSTOMER_ID,MAX(a.LST_UPDT_TS) LST_UPDT_TS FROM TableA as a group by a.CUST_ID 
UNION
SELECT b.CUST_ID as CUSTOMER_ID,MAX(b.LST_UPDT_TS) LST_UPDT_TS FROM TableB as b group by b.CUST_ID 
UNION
SELECT c.CUST_ID as CUSTOMER_ID,MAX(c.LST_UPDT_TS) LST_UPDT_TS FROM TableC as c group by c.CUST_ID 
) d GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY 2 DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```